# How do I change element values only inside media query?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu using html and css. However, when I change something in media query it also affects the same elements that's outside of it. Specifically,I have a horizontal navigation bar and I have sentered the links
vertically using "align-items:center".It works, but it also align my items the same way inside the media query.(on the dropdown, they appear in the middle"vertically" while I want them to me on top(x,y = 0).
I basically want my links inside media to be placed at the top while the same link outside the media to stay aligned.
Thank you..

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (max-width:650px) {
    #links{
        background-color:red;
        position:fixed;
        inset:0 0 0 50%;
        z-index:20;
        align-self: flex-end;
    }
    #links ul{
        flex-direction:column;
        background-color: white;
    }

}
#img{
    width:3em;
    height:3em;
}
#header-img{
    display:flex;
}

#header{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
#nav-bar{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
#links{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
#links ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    display:flex;
    gap:5rem;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;

}
.main {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 68px;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 98%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.plans {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.column {
  width: 90%;
  max-width:280px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 30em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px grey;
}
.column_3,
.column_2,
.column_1 {
  margin: 20px 20px;
}
.column h5 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.column h5 p {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.pricing {
  height: 52%;
  margin-top: -22px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.pricing_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
#link_one {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: .8em;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: transparent;
}
#link_one:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#link_two {
  font-size:.8em;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#link_two:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
#below_button {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.checks {
  width: 100%;
}
.checks ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.checks ul li:before {
  content: "✓";
  padding-right: 8px;
  color: rgb(0, 230, 0);
}
ul li {
  text-indent: -1.25em;
}
.separator {
  height: 1px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.benefits {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.fa-solid {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  color: rgb(0, 250, 0);
}
.rectangle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width:300px;
}

.footer {
  width: 75%;
  height: 200px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  position: static;
}
.contact_info {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.icons_left ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px 30px;
}
.icons_left ul li {
  padding: 0 40px;
  color: white;
}
.contact_right {
  font-size: 1.05em;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: white;
}

.footer .fa-2x:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 250, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1724737a9d.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div id="header">
        <div id="header-img">
          <img
            id="img"
            src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/gorilla/gorilla_PNG18705.png"
            alt=""
          />
          <h2>Gorilla Drive</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="nav-bar">
          <nav id="links">
            <ul>
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Deals</a></li>
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Benefits</a></li>
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main">
        <div class="plans">
          <div class="column column_1">
            <h5>
              Basic<br />
              <p>100 GB</p>
            </h5>
            <div class="pricing">
              <div class="pricing_content">
                <a id="link_one" href="#">$2,99/month</a>
                <i id="below_button">Pay annualy (save 100%)</i>
                <a id="link_two" href="">$20,99/year</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="separator"></div>
            <div class="checks">
              <ul class="check_links">
                <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor lahim.</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column column_2">
            <h5>
              Standard<br />
              <p>1 TB</p>
            </h5>
            <div class="pricing">
              <div class="pricing_content">
                <a id="link_one" href="#">$2,99/month</a>
                <i id="below_button">Pay annualy (save 100%)</i>
                <a id="link_two" href="">$20,99/year</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="separator"></div>
            <div class="checks">
              <ul class="check_links">
                <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor lahim.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor lahim baban.</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column column_3">
            <h5>
              Premium<br />
              <p>2 TB</p>
            </h5>
            <div class="pricing">
              <div class="pricing_content">
                <a id="link_one" href="#">$2,99/month</a>
                <i id="below_button">Pay annualy (save 100%)</i>
                <a id="link_two" href="">$20,99/year</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="separator"></div>
            <div class="checks">
              <ul class="check_links">
                <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor lahim.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor lahim baban.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor lahim baban sahim.</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="benefits">
          <div class="rectangle rectangle_1">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-fire fa-4x"></i>
            <h4><b>High quality!</b></h4>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis
              ullamcorper posuere nisi eu finibus.
            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="rectangle rectangle_2">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-jet-fighter-up fa-4x"></i>
            <h4><b>Jet Fast support!</b></h4>
            <p>
              Proin feugiat sem tellus, commodo lacinia dui viverra ac. Sed
              sollicitudin non metus sed sagittis. Nunc at tincidunt magna.
            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="rectangle rectangle_3">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-user-group fa-4x"></i>
            <h4><b>Share with your family!</b></h4>
            <p>
              Aliquam vel mi blandit, venenatis risus vel, pellentesque nisl.
              Suspendisse et sem leo.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c3wk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add the flowing to the `#links ul` directly

```
 #links ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

and remove

```
ul li {
    text-indent: -1.25em;
}
```